# D3 Line Chart curved segments

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Using Multi Line Charts in D3, I an trying to alter the properties of each line segment (change color & width) while applying the interpolate() function which curves the line.

However, when I draw the line by giving the x1,y1 & x2,y2 coordinates (as opposed to line(data)), the curve function does not get applied.

Below is the current code which specifies the x1,y1 and x2,y2 coordinates of the line. With this I am able to change the properties of each line segment.

```
// Line deceleration

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.percent_change); });

// Construction of lines

payer.selectAll(“line”)
.data(function(d){return d.values})
.enter()
.append(‘line’)
.attr(“class”, “line”)
.attr(‘x1’, function(d) { return x(d.prev_x); })
.attr(‘y1’, function(d) { return y(d.prev_y); })
.attr(‘x2’, function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr(‘y2’, function(d) { return y(d.percent_change); })
.style(“stroke”, function(d) { if(d.prev_y>d.percent_change){return ‘#ffcccc’} else{return ‘#adebad’} })
.style(“stroke-width”, function(d) {return 100*Math.abs(d.percent_change)});
```

The Issue I’m having now is that I need to apply a curve to the lines which should be done using the interpolate()  function (D3 v3). I was able to do this before I applied the variable path width and color to each line segment using the following code.

```
// Line deceleration

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.percent_change); })
.interpolate(“monotone”);

// Construction of Line

payer.append(“path”)
.attr(“class”, “line”)
.attr(“d”, function(d) { return line(d.values); })
.style(“stroke”, function(d) { return “#a6a6a6”; });
```

However, now that I’ve included the ability to manipulate the line width and color using the described code, I do not see the line curving feature being applied. How can I make it so that I can have curved lines while keeping the ability to change the attributes of each line segment?

Current implementation:

```
// Line deceleration

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.percent_change); })
.interpolate(“monotone”); // Not being applied

// Construction of lines

payer.selectAll(“line”)
.data(function(d){return d.values})
.enter()
.append(‘line’)
.attr(“class”, “line”)
.attr(‘x1’, function(d) { return x(d.prev_x); })
.attr(‘y1’, function(d) { return y(d.prev_y); })
.attr(‘x2’, function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr(‘y2’, function(d) { return y(d.percent_change); })
.style(“stroke”, function(d) { if(d.prev_y>d.percent_change){return ‘#ffcccc’} else{return ‘#adebad’} })
.style(“stroke-width”, function(d) {return 100*Math.abs(d.percent_change)});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a chance to dig a little deeper and this is what I found.

My first mistake should have been obvious. When I switched from using the line() 
function to specifying the x1y1 & x2y2 coordinates, the interpolation algorithm was 
not being called anymore.

To apply the curve at every segment of the line being drawn, I found a way to specify 
the svg path directly. This is how I did it.

```
    // Line creation in D3

    var randomnumner = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    payer.selectAll(“link”)
    .data(function(d){return d.values})
    .enter()
    .append(‘path’)
    .attr(“d”, function(d) {return curvedline(d)})
    .style(“stroke”, function(d) { if((d.prev_x>0 && d.percent_change<0) || (d.prev_x<0 && d.percent_change>0)) {
    return ‘url(#linear-gradient)’;
    } else {
    return ‘#cccccc’;
    }
    })
    .attr(“fill”, “none”)
    .attr(“stroke-width”, function() {return randomNumGen()});

    // Draw SVG curved line. M defines the starting point and C denotes a cubic bezier curve.

    function curvedline(d) {

    return “M” + x(d.prev_x) + “,” + y(d.prev_y) // starting point // this section (and the one above) is drawing M=moveto command of svg path
    + “C” + x(d.prev_x+(d.prev_x – d.percent_change)/10) + “,” + y(mid_date2) //control point 1 // C curveto command of svg path
    + ” ” + x(d.percent_change+(d.prev_x – d.percent_change)/10) + “,” + y(mid_date1)
    + ” ” + x(d.percent_change) + “,” + y(d.date); //ending point
    }
```